# How to pause video on model close (videojs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, video.js

What I have :

```
<script>
  function stopvideos()
  { 
    $(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
   //$("#example_video_0").pause(); 
   //$("#example_video_0").get(0).pause();
   //jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
   //$("#example_video_0").trigger("pause");
   //$("#example_video_0").player.pause();
   // $('#example_video_1').remove();
   /*VideoJS.DOMReady(function(){
       var myPlayer = VideoJS.setup("example_video_0");
       myPlayer.pause();  
    });
   */ 
}
  </script>
<div id="animation-reel">
    <a class="bClose" onclick="stopvideos();">x<a/>
     <video id="example_video_0" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="210" height="118"
      poster="videos/video-js_poster.jpg" 
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="videos/animation.m4v" type='video/mp4' />
      <!--<source src="peo_v10.webm" type='video/webm' />
      <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
      <track kind="captions" src="videos/captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" />-->
    </video>
  </div>
```

What I tried :

```
1. $(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
2. $("#example_video_0").pause(); 
3. $("#example_video_0").get(0).pause();
4. jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
5. $("#example_video_0").trigger("pause");
6. $("#example_video_0").player.pause();
7. $('#example_video_1').remove();
8. VideoJS.DOMReady(function(){
    var myPlayer = VideoJS.setup("example_video_0");
     myPlayer.pause();  
   });
```

What I want :

Pause video click on model close link < a class="bClose" onclick="stopvideos();">x< a / >

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this **Working Example**  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNfW8/4/)

Simply access video element by

```
var vid = document.getElementById("example_video_0");
vid.pause();
```

Enjoy..!

Comment: Can u plz share your code to test and did u tried fiddle example ?

Comment: Hello friend, it works nice on fiddle but when I copy whole code and Make a html file and run it on browser, then not working .

Answer (score 0):

just remove src of iframe, it will stop playing video after close of model

```
$('button.close').click(function(){
    $('iframe').attr('src','');;
});
```